# How to handle null values while querying with distinct column values condition from the same table

Tags: postgresql

There is a single table named Products which has 100s of columns. I am running a distinct column1,column2,column3....column6 postgresql query and the result is something like below:

```
2    Product A  300  2017  Null  Null
2    Product A  300  2017  Null  Null
```

Due to null values, instead of a single row I am getting two rows. How to solve this? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure that a distinct query by itself should be giving you this result set.  Please include your actual query and some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

`null` differs from itself, distinct checks for equality under the hood. Instead of

```
select distinct field1, field2, ..., fieldn
```

you can have your select clause like this:

```
select distinct coalesce(field1, 'Empty') AS field1, ..., coalesce(fieldn, 'Empty') AS fieldn
```

You will only need `coalesce` for nullable fields.

Comment: One nitpicky correction: NULL does *not* differ from itself, but it is unknown if two unknown values are equal or not (`(NULL = NULL) IS NULL`).

Comment: Now, I get Empty replacing Null still with duplicate rows. Tried COALESCE(NULLIF(Field1,''), Field2) as well. Issue still not solved.

Comment: @Tony can you edit your question and show us your current attempt?

Answer (score 0):

One way to remove the duplicates you have above is to use `GROUP BY` the columns that you want distinct values for. So something like this

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...,column6
FROM sometable
GROUP BY column1, column2, column3, ...,column6
```

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what I am trying to do. However, still duplicate rows are occurring in the result set with null values for some columns. If I remove the columns which have null values for a given entry and then run the query, I get only a single row. The duplication of rows happens only when null values are present since distinct is not able to handle them.